# What's the thred id of dbcc sqlperf('threads')?

Tags: sql-server

There is a session running for a long time and `dbcc sqlperf('threads')` shows a "Thread ID" has the status of Running.

How to kill the thread?

Comment: The thread is linked to a session, and the session has a particular SPID. You can execute `KILL 999` where 999 is the SPID of that particular thread. That will initiate the rollback procedure if it had open transactions.

Comment: I tried `kill 999` and it has been in the status of `SPID 999: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.` forever. It has been waiting for OLEDB (linked server).

Comment: This is a know issue with never-ending transactions that rely on external systems (like xp_cmdshell or linked servers), it will most likely never end until you restart the server. The important thing is to check if it's using resources like CPU or memory or not. Please read https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/31/sql-server-spid-is-killedrollback-state-what-to-do-next/

Comment: I see. That's the reason I'm wondering if it's possible to kill the external thread to make the rollback finished.

Comment: you can't manage external resources from SQL Server, you can try to check the remote's server operation (the statement from the linked server) and kill it if you have the privileges and it *may* finish your SQL Server operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for it in the processes and use the sql command KILL followed by the spid number, eventually you cn compose the kill as a column to have a ready to use copy and paste like this:

```
select top 100 'KILL '+cast(spid as varchar) as command, * from sys.sysprocesses where cmd like 'DBCC%'
```

Comment: I tried `kill 999` and it has been in the status of `SPID 999: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.` forever. It has been waiting for OLEDB (linked server).